# Does Python import statement also import dependencies automatically?

Tags: python, function, python-import

I have the following file `app.py`

```
class Baz():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.a = num
        print self.a

def foo(num):
    obj = Baz(num)
```

and the second file `main.py`

```
from app import foo
foo(10)
```

Running the file `python main.py` gives the correct output.

Now in the second file, I'm just importing the function not the class, although successful execution of my function requires the class as well.

When importing the function does Python automatically import everything else which is needed to run that function, or does it automatically search for the class in the current directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @DavidZ already mentioned the whole Python file gets compiled when we import it. But another special thing happens when a function body is parsed, a function knows which variables it should look for in local scope and which variables it should look for in global scope(well there are free variables too).

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  7           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Baz)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (num)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (obj)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

So, here `Baz` must be fetched from global scope.

> But how to identify this global scope when we import app.py in another
>   file?

Well, each function has a special attribute `__globals__` attached to it which contains its actual global namespace. Hence, that's the source of `Baz`:

```
>>> foo.__globals__['Baz']
<class __main__.Baz at 0x10f6e1c80>
```

So, app's module dictionary and `foo.__globals__` point to the same object:

```
>>>sys.modules['app'].__dict__ is foo.__globals__ 
True
```

Due to this even if you define another variable named `Baz` in `main.py` after importing `foo` it will still access the actual `Baz`.

From [data-model page](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html):

`__globals__ func_globals`:

> A reference to the dictionary that holds the function’s global
>   variables — the global namespace of the **module in which the function
>   was defined**.

Comment: This is neat. So I should never put unrelated code in one file if my intention is to just load a single function, because Python will always compile the whole file, right?

Comment: @KartikAnand Python will compile it only once to a `.pyc` file, later imports simply fetch the bytecode from that same `.pyc` file until you again update the `.py` file.

Comment: So if I am not explicitly importing `Baz`, can I instantiate it by accessing it from `__globals__` attached to the function?

Comment: @KartikAnand Yes. Well you can access the whole module using `import sys;sys.modules['app']`. Imports are cached in Python. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache

Comment: So it's just good practice to import whatever you need instead of accessing it using `sys.modules dict`

Comment: @KartikAnand Yes, you can import from a particular module how many times you want because the actual import happens only once. But unnecessary variable imports will only flood your namespace that's the reason `from x import *` are discouraged, so import only those things that are required. To handle implicit imports properly learn how Python's import machinery works.
With that said we are moving too much away from your actual question now. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Python does not automatically do any of these things.

When you import something from a module (in this case, the `app` module), Python first runs all the code in the corresponding file (`app.py`). The code in the file `app.py` which you've written does two things:

1. define the class `Baz`
2. define the function `foo`

When the function `foo` runs, Python looks for `Baz` in the module that `foo` is part of, and only there. (Well, it also checks local variables defined in the function `foo`, but you don't have any of those except `obj`.) Specifically, it looks for `app.Baz`. If you alter your `main.py` to do the same search:

```
from app import foo
foo(10)
import app # same app that was already imported
print app.Baz
```

you will see that `app.Baz` is the class you defined in `app.py`.

If you put the definition of class `Baz` in yet another file, and if you don't import that file, Python will not run it. This shows that Python does *not* automatically import dependencies. In particular, suppose `app.py` contains

```
def foo(num):
    obj = Baz(num)
```

and `baz.py` contains

```
class Baz():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.a = num
        print self.a
```

and `main.py` is unchanged. You'll get an error because Python has not run the code to define the class `Baz`.

Comment: I know about the definition part. When it runs the file, does it store the definition part of the Class in some form in the current file?