# Does importing a class from another file also import that files dependencies?

Tags: python, import, dependencies

Say I have a script called src.py with several functions defined in it; the functions are all in a class called `LDA`. These functions need libraries such as `numpy`, `scipy` and others, which are imported as standard at the top of the script.

Now in a new separate script, called `main.py`, I import the class `LDA`:

```
from src import LDA
```

If I now use the `LDA` class and all its functions in the new `main.py` script, the functions all work correctly, *even though I did not import the dependencies needed in `src.py`*. **How does this work?** Shouldn't I need to import `numpy`, `scipy` and so on in `main.py` for `LDA` to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This and similar questions have already been answered here. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367255/does-python-import-statement-also-import-dependencies-automatically) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import?noredirect=1&lq=1) to understand the significance of python `import module` and `from module import class` features.

In summary both `import X` and `from X import class` executes the target file line by line so all the dependencies will automatically be loaded in the module's namespace. So if you instantiate the class and run the functions/methods they will be looked up in the namespace (a fancy dictionary) of X where references to the dependencies are present. The `from X import class` creates a reference to `class` with the same name after importing so it can be used without qualification. But the caveat is the module X has no reference so the objects cannot be accessed with X.obj qualifier. With an ordinary `import X` statement you can access all the objects defined in X.

Side Note: The dir() function and **dict** attribute of an imported object is a great way to see what objects are loaded. An example is given below

```
#script test.py
import numpy as np

class Baz():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.a = np.arange(num)
        self.b = np.ones(num)
        print self.a, self.b

    def foo(self):
        prod = np.dot(self.a, self.b)
        return prod

>>> import test
>>> dir(test)
['Baz', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'np']
>>> test.__dict__.keys()
['__builtins__', '__file__', 'Baz', '__package__', 'np', '__name__', '__doc__']
>>> test.__dict__['np']
<module 'numpy' from '/home/user/bin/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'>
>>> x = test.Baz(5)
[0 1 2 3 4] [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
>>> x.foo()
10.0
```

Now the from import statement

```
>>> from test import Baz
>>> dir(test)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
>>> dir(Baz)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'foo']
>>> Baz.__module__
'test'
>>> Baz.__dict__.keys()
['__module__', 'foo', '__doc__', '__init__']
>>> x = Baz(5)
[0 1 2 3 4] [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
>>> x.foo()
10.0
>>> Baz.__dict__['foo'].__globals__.keys()
['__builtins__', '__file__', 'Baz', '__package__', 'np', '__name__', '__doc__']
```

As you can see the module numpy is loaded and available in the `__globals__` attribute of the function which again returns the dictionary of all loaded modules. So when the `foo()` method is run it performs a lookup in the namespace dictionary and locates numpy.