# How does importing 1 function only that depends on another work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, python-import

What if we have a module that contains two functions and we import only one of them, will the other work?For instance:

file test.py

`def a(x):print(x)
 def b():a(12)`

At the interpreter:

> > from test import b
> >
> > b()

It prints 12.How is this possible?Please pardon my bad formatting that's my first question :).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python import statement also import dependencies automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367255/does-python-import-statement-also-import-dependencies-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Technically there is no such thing as importing a single name from a module; the *entire module* is imported and then one or more names are copied to the local namespace. Your import is roughly the equivalent of:

```
import test
b = test.b
del test
```

Except that at no point is `test` ever actually in the local namespace (and subsequently is not actually deleted).